# como ocultar una imagen en css cuando llegue a los 380 px desaparesca la imagen

Tags: css

tengo un proyecto donde requiero que cuando llegue a los 380px desaparezca las imágenes. lo he intentado con @media pero creo que no estoy utilizando bien el procedimiento.

Comment: agrega el css con el media query para ver el problema. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/241577/edit) tu pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .imagen {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="imagen" src="https://picsum.photos/1024/768">
```

Comment: bueno en si me funciona este sintaxis, pero lo estoy desarrollando en en ambiente mvc en .net c# y pues no me funciona como quiero

Comment: @DayverUicab En ese caso, agrega tu código conflictivo y las etiquetas correspondientes en tu pregunta... Con la información que muestras no es suficiente para saber con que herramientas estás desarrollando. Te invito a leer la sección [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te des una idea de cómo funciona SO.